# PHP <?= tag used in Magento2

Tags: php, magento2, php-5.4

In the file `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\Html\Header.phtml` I see this code `<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>` and I think PHP 4 is being used in Magento2.

```
<li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
                <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : '<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Magento 2 does not use PHP 4. From PHP 5.4 short tags `<?=` are available by default and cannot be switched off. So you can use it in templates, like in the example.

Comment: Kudos for understanding the question and providing the correct answer

Comment: The Magento core team and several community members discussed the merits of using the shorthand echo syntax throughout the codebase in June of 2015, but ultimately the decision was made to not refactor all code to use it: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/107#issuecomment-110936259

Answer (score 5):

The tag being used is `<?=` which is the short/inline echo tag. It looks like the use of the [short open tag](http://php.net/basic-syntax.phptags) which looks like `<?  /*... code ...*/  ?>` which is used instead of the full PHP tags `<?php  /*... code ...*/  ?>`

The short echo tag tag however is slightly different. The syntax `<?="Hello Magento SE"?>` is a shorter alternative to `<?php echo "Hello Magento SE"; ?>`.

Before PHP 5.4 you had to turn on the `short_open_tag` setting to be able to use the short echo tag. From PHP 5.4.0 the short echo tag is available by default independent of the `short_open_tag` setting. Using short open tags is discouraged, using short echo tag is not. If your code needs to work with PHP <5.4 then it is also discouraged to use the short echo tag as you are forcing users to turn on short open tags.

[The Magento2 docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html) say to use PHP 5.5.x at minimum, so Magento2 can use short echo tags without the above mentioned implication.

**UPDATE:**

Since the current 2.2.0 version of Magento 2 is only supporting PHP 7, using short echo tags is no problem (backwards compatibility is no longer needed). Also [this pull request](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/1563) on the Magento 2 GitHub was merged, changing all (?) PHP `<?php echo ... ?>` occurrences in templates to the short version `<?= ... ?>`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is related to PHP4 but to the [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting in php.ini.
As of PHP 5.4, `<?= ... ?>` tags are supported everywhere, regardless of shorttags settings. This should mean they're safe to use in portable code but that does mean there's then a dependency on PHP 5.4+. If you want to support pre-5.4 and can't guarantee shorttags, you'll still need to use `<?php echo ... ?>`

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the [August 2014 EOL of pre-5.4](http://php.net/eol.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 may be used PHP 5.4. But on installing it involves readiness check it accepts only above php version 5.4+

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use the PHP `<?= ?>` tag used in Magento2 then create a php.ini file in root and enable the `short_open_tag`
even you can change more setting via php.ini file